# Declare array of matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, declaration

I'm new in the magic python world.

1)I need to have an array (arrMtx) where each element of this vector is a matrix.
How I can declare the array arrMtx?

2)I suppose for filling the arrMtx I should do something like that:

```
mtx = [[0.0 for x in range(NUM_COLUMN)] for x in range(NUM_ROW)] 
arrMtx[i] = mtx
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: So, you want a list of 2d arrays? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NUM_COLUMN = 4
NUM_ROW = 2
NUM_MATRIX = 3
mtx = [[0.0 for x in range(NUM_COLUMN)] for x in range(NUM_ROW)] 
arrMtx = [mtx for x in range(NUM_MATRIX)]
print arrMtx
```

Output:

```
[[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of 2d arrays (matrices):

```
num_matrices = 3 ## Let's say
ncol = 3
nrow = 3
arrMtx = [[[0 for j in range(ncol)] for i in range(nrow)] for k in range(num_matrices)]
```

Output:

```
>>>[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simply, where `n` is no. of elemnts in `arrMtx`

```
>>>[[[0.0 for x in range(NUM_COLUMN)] for x in range(NUM_ROW)]]*n #no. of elements
```

That means

```
>>>mtx = [[0.0 for x in range(NUM_COLUMN)] for x in range(NUM_ROW)]
>>>arrMtx = [mtx] * n
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, [Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) are use like `vector in c++`.

In a list, you can [append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) as you like:

```
L = [0,1,2,3....]
```

After append list will be:

```
L.append('str')
L = [0,1,2,3,'str'....]
```

So, you can anything append you can want.

So make a **matrix**, you need `list of list` like:

```
L = [[....], [.....]....]

mtx = [[0.0 for x in range(NUM_COLUMN)] for x in range(NUM_ROW)]
```

Here **mtx** is also a **matrix**. you can **append** it into another list:

```
arrMtx = [] 
arrMtx.append(mtx)
```

**Question 1 answer:**

You can declare the `array arrMtx` like:

```
arrMtx = []
```

It's create a list. Then you append a list, it will be an array.